# Search for a string in json array and retrieve its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm new to Json and javascript I have the following code and i created a json array :

```
<script>

function cost_change(price) {
    var removed;
    var value = <?php echo json_encode(Yii::app()->params['match_resales']);?>;
    console.log("value",value);     

}
</script>
```

Now, `price` is a string that needs to be searched in the json array and if found its value has to be retrieved.
Json array printed is like this  `Object { 100000.0="1lakh", 200000.0="2lakh", 300000.0="3lakh"}`.Suppose price="100000.0" then I should get var removed=1lakh. How to do this

Comment: Isn't value[price] working?

Comment: Note that even though you use `json_encode`, the problem has nothing to do with JSON, since the output is interpreted as object literal.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON that should be printed for Javascript would be as follows:

```
{ 100000.0: "1lakh", 200000.0: "2lakh", 300000.0: "3lakh" }
```

That would then work as expected in your function. PHP json_encode **should** print it out like this rather than the sample you posted. So, there may be an issue with the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The JSon being retrieved is not an array, but an object. That's important. It means that:

1. You can use the first element as a key to access each member (item).
2. You cannot use it as a regular array (that's why it gets printed out as an object). E.g., it has no "length".

Having said that, you can remove a member from an object this simple:

```
    delete value[parseInt(price)];
```

here we are:

1. Accessing the value "object" using an array notation, having the key to return the whole member.
2. Transforming the *string* price into a number (I'm assuming all of them ends with .0, otherwise you should use parse float).
3. Deleting that member from the object.